# Rabbitmq and nodejs delete queue after message has been received

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Im new in the rabbitmq, trying to figure out how to delete queue after message has been received. Any help appreciated. Here is consumer script:

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");
let result = connect();

async function connect() {

    try {
        const amqpServer = "amqp://localhost"
        const connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer)
        const channel = await connection.createChannel();
        await channel.assertQueue("jobs");

        channel.consume("jobs", message => {
            const input = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
            console.log(`Recieved job with input ${input}`);
        })
        console.log("Waiting for messages...");
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex)
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to delete the message from the queue or delete the queue?

Comment: Im trying to delete the queue after message has been received

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`assertQueue` queue docs](https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/channel_api.html#channel_assertQueue), you can pass an `autoDelete` option when creating which will clean up after the number of consumers drops to 0.

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");
let result = connect();

async function connect() {

    try {
        const amqpServer = "amqp://localhost"
        const connection = await amqp.connect(amqpServer)
        const channel = await connection.createChannel();
        await channel.assertQueue("jobs", {autoDelete: true});

        channel.consume("jobs", message => {
            const input = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());
            console.log(`Recieved job with input ${input}`);
        })
        console.log("Waiting for messages...");
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex)
    }
}
```

You could then call [`cancel`](https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/channel_api.html#channel_cancel) on the channel to stop consuming the messages.

```
channel.cancel("jobs");
```

Lastly, you could forcefully delete the queue with [`deleteQueue`](https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/channel_api.html#channel_deleteQueue), although this might have some strange side effects if doing it in a callback.